ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed, when importing mysqldump into mariadb
I prepared a dump of a MySQL database using the following command in PowerShell:
mysqldump db_name -u root -p > transfer.sql
I then moved the file to another computer which was running MariaDB and imported the file using the following command:
mariabd db_name -u root -p < transfer.sql
This resulted in the following error:

ERROR: ASCII '\0' appeared in the statement, but this is not allowed unless option --binary-mode is enabled and mysql is run in non-interactive mode. Set --binary-mode to 1 if ASCII '\0' is expected. Query: '��/'.

I tried setting the binary-mode, but it didn't help. I inspected the dump and saw a line at the beginning that said SET NAMES utf8mb4;, which seems to be the correct encoding. I tried exporting with --hex-blob and --default-character-set=utf8mb4, but neither of these worked.
How can I export a database from MySQL and get MariaDB to import it correctly?

error message in subject different from body?

@ysth thanks for pointing it out; I had pasted the wrong error initially

It turns out that it wasn't a MySQL issue so much as a PowerShell issue. Apparently, the > operator in PowerShell converts everything to UTF-16 by default (see related question). Instead, I had to export using
mysqldump db_name -u root -p | Out-File transfer.sql -Encoding utf8
After that, I also had to adjust the collation by using find and replace in transfer.sql to replace utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci with utf8mb4_unicode_ci, and the import worked perfectly after that.
Hope this helps.

You can also use the option mysqldump --result-file=transfer.sql ...other options... instead of piping its stdout.

Adjusting utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci to utf8mb4_1400_ai_ci is probably a better option. MariaDB is contemplating aliasing them to make migration easier.
